# Assume an encrypted message is sent through use of exponential cipher.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, exponentiation, cryptography, mathematica

...such that modulus $p = 2741 \text{ (p is prime)}$ and $e = 11 \text{ (e = exponent)}$

Message: $1315\quad 0611 \quad 0427 \quad 0091 \quad 0520 \quad 0733$

I am required to determine the decryption exponent and determine what it says.

This is my work so far on Mathematica. I believe my solution is wrong, as
the exponent I arrived at is negative. Please advise. Thanks in advance.

---

'In' =input 
'Out' =output

In $ \text{mssg} = { 1315, 0611, 0427, 0091, 0520, 0733}$

Out ${1315, 611, 427, 91, 520, 733}$

In $p = 2741$

In $e = 11$

In $\text {code[x_]} := \mod[x^{e}, p]$

In $\text { cipher  = code[mssg] }$

Out $\, {2622, 2659, 1544, 951, 2718, 859}$

In $\text{ ExtendedGCD }[e, p - 1]$

Out $\,(1, (-249, 1))$

> Why do my exponent here shows as $-249 ?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, The Mathematica online help page about [ExtendedGCD](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExtendedGCD.html) gives limited information about this;

\begin{align}
in[1]:&\; \{g, \{a, b\}\} = \operatorname{ExtendedGCD}[2, 3]\\
out[1]:&\; \{1,\{-1,1\}\} \quad \text{ //next, test the result}\\ 
in[2]: &\;2 a + 3 b == g\\
out[2]:&\; \texttt{True}\\
\end{align}

The extra output sub-list is for the [Bezout's Identity.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity):

> Let $a$ and $b$ be integers with greatest common divisor $d$. Then, there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax + by = d$

For your problem;

\begin{align}
 \gcd(e,p-1) &= u \cdot e + v \cdot (p-1), \text{ for some } u,v\in\mathbb{Z}\\
1  &=  -249 \cdot 11 + 1 \cdot 2740\\
1  &=  -2739 +  2740
\end{align}

Actually, you want the inverse of $e$ $\bmod{p-1}$ and Bezout's Identity that is very helpful to find the inverses.

If you take $\bmod 2740$ on both side - that is one of the ways to calculate the inverse -;

$$ 1  =  -249 \cdot 11 + 1 \cdot 2740$$

$$ 1  \equiv  -249 \cdot 11 \pmod{2740}$$

you fill find the inverse of $11 \pmod{2740}$, that is $-249 \equiv 2491 \bmod 2740$

Comment: So 1315 decrypts to $1315^{2491} \pmod{2740}=2415$ (yo?), 0611 to $611^{2491} \pmod{2740}=2291$ (?) etc.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Well, not exactly. $1315^{2491} \color{red}{\pmod{2741}} = 1916$ and  $611^{2491} \pmod{2741} = 1809$.

Comment: Quite right... sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma always welcome.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, much appreciated. However, is there a code in Mathematica that will help me translate the code into letters? Please advise. Thanks again!

Comment: @user711963 Actually, Henno Brandsma, gave you the hint. Take mod 100, div 100, and you get the char in terms of $A=0,..,Z=26$.

Comment: @kelalaka  Thank you both!